# How to make middle mouse button to work normally with preventDefault() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to open link in new tab with middle mouse button, but I find out that `event.preventDefault()` stops middle-click from opening a new tab.

I have to use `event.preventDefault()` because my link is used for trigger a lightbox, but I want user to be able to open this link in new tab with middle mouse button too, how can I do that?

**Demo**

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a id="test" target="_blank" href="//jsbin.com/wemowe">Click</a>
```

Comment: Note that the [*W3C DOM 3 Events specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) states that only the primary (usually left) mouse button dispatches a click event, all other buttons must not. You should use either the *mousedown* or *mouseup* event as appropriate.

Comment: @RobG - if the middle button doesn't dispatch a click event, if won't trigger the lightbox, and this wouldn't be an issue, so using the `click` event is fine here, especially since preventing the other events won't stop the anchor from redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it conditional so it doesn't prevent the middle mouse button, which is `2`

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if ( e.which !== 2 )
         e.preventDefault();
});
```

A somewhat more cross browser solution supporting older IE as well would be

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var evt = (e == null ? event : e), prevented = true;

    if (evt.which) {
        if (evt.which == 2) prevented = false;
    } else if (evt.button) {
        if (evt.button == 4) prevented = false;
    }

    if (prevented) evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Do we have any other option?

Comment: @crezc3nt - uhm, why would you need an other option ?

Comment: Your solution make the middle mouse button to open link in new tab and trigger my lightbox too (in my demo, the link turn red). I updated my demo, take a look

Comment: Button events are a bit of a mess, *event.which* [*is in the process of being removed*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.which). The W3C DOM 3 Events [*Interface MouseEvent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mouseevents) specification says the auxiliary (usually middle) button is 1 and that the secondary (usually right) button is 2.

Comment: @RobG - `event.which` is still supported in all browsers, except maybe IE, did'nt really check, and it is consistent in `2` being the middle button. Of coursem using `event.button` would have been better, if they could just agree on the numbers, the middle button could  return `1`, or it could return `4` in IE, where `1` is the left button, making it harder to write something that is cross browser.